# How to add spacing between key value pairs when writing JSON to file

Tags: json, flutter, file

I have a json file that displays values in one very long line.

[image: json Line]

I would like to show it in more clean and easy to read manner with spacing and multiple lines.

[image: desired look]

Below is the code for writing json object to file.

```
      var jsonEncoded = jsonEncode(_json);
      configFile.writeAsString(jsonEncoded);
```

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Since the problem is of visual nature, I thought an image is the best way to explain it. However, for the code part i will use code blocks.

Comment: It's not visual in nature: It's text in nature. Please remove all links to images and use plain text formatter as code instead.

Comment: What is the type of `configFile`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can format your JSON.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print(prettyJson({"glossary":{"title":"example glossary"}}));
}

String prettyJson(dynamic json) {
    var spaces = ' ' * 4;
    var encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent(spaces);
    return encoder.convert(json);
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary"
    }
}
```

Try out to put your JSON into that function and get the output.

Comment: My output becomes unusable if i do that. 
  "{\"noOfSteps\":4,\"stepHour\":[0,0,0,0],

Comment: I would like to add that my value in my key value pair is a list, so { " glossary ": [0, 1 ,2 ] }

Comment: Remove double quotes as I haven't given in function.